# Laravel Image showing if write port in address but xampp is wierd

Tags: laravel, image, xampp, localhost, port

I have this address and show the image if call artisan serve with port 8000 !

http://localhost:8000/storage/images/2024/02/11/img1.jpg

if I try it with this :

```
php artisan serve --port=80
```

address must be this one :

http://localhost:80/storage/images/2024/02/11/img1.jpg

and browser doing what I need and remove the port like this :

http://localhost/storage/images/2024/02/11/img1.jpg

but the image will not show and page 404 will apper

what I have to do with xampp !

if you need some detail about set index.php and httpd.conf I did what is necessary

remove ../ for index in root folder

and put name of project for xampp httpd.conf

Comment: create a virtual host on xampp and point to `public` folder of your project. `artisan serve` has nothing to do with xampp as it runs it's own server